# How to trigger trailing stop loss once some profit has been made?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In Pine, I made a long entry order, along with an exit order (with a profit and stop loss condition)

```
strategy.entry("My Long Entry ", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("My Exit 1", profit=15000, loss=15000, qty_percent = 50 ,from_entry = "My Long Entry ", comment_profit="madeProfit")
```

I also want to activate a trailing stop loss order (with the rest of the 50% investment) once the "My exit 1" has been closed, I have tried this:

```
if strategy.closedtrades.exit_comment(strategy.opentrades - 1) == "madeProfit"
    strategy.exit("My Exit 2", from_entry = "My Long Entry ", trail_offset=15000, trail_points=0)
```

I never see this triggered on the chart, so I think there is something wrong with the "if" statement.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `strategy.exit` an `if` is not needed

```
strategy.exit("My Exit 2", from_entry = "My Long Entry ", trail_offset=15000, trail_points=0)
```